# Jquery Validation Plugin, dynamic form validation

Tags: jquery-validate, jquery

I'm using the  [Jquery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to forms loaded via Ajax (dynamic forms). I know that as of Jquery 1.4, live events on submit is now possible. Now the problem is I want to show a confirm message after the dynamic form has been validated. My code looks like this:

```
$('.dynamicForm').live('submit',function(){
   $(this).validate();
   if($(this).valid()){
      if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
         e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

It's not working as expected. Somehow confirmation shows first, then at the second time I submit the form, that's the time the validation happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow this seems to work:

```
$('.dynamicForm').live('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler:function(form){
            if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards. Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 3):

Use the `submitHandler` function available in the [validate options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#topoptions):

```
$(".dynamicForm").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) { //Only runs when valid
     if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
       form.submit();
   }
})
```

From the docs - **submitHandler**:

> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

Comment: I've tried that. But the real problem is dealing with dynamic form elements. That's why I used Jquery's live().