# jQuery validation fails when using KnockoutJS and Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a form which is rendered using html.RenderAction in MVC3.

Outside of this I have a jquery template used with knockout.  The model is rendered correctly into the view with the default 'data-val-required' attributes.

However I've noticed that jQuery validation always returns true.

```
<div id="dlgAdd" data-bind="template: { name: 'editTemplate', data: selected }">
</div>
<script id="editTemplate" type="text/html">  
<div> 
@{
    Html.RenderAction("EditDialog");
}
</div>    
</script>
```

The EditDialog partial renders the following output like so:

```
 <form method="post" id="frmAddNew" action="/Project/AddNew"> 
    <div class="fields-inline">         
       <div class="editor-label">             
          <label for="Name">Name</label>         
       </div>         

       <div class="editor-field">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="ko_unique_41" value="" type="text">
          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <span id="validationmessage" class="field-validation-error"></span>   
  </form>
```

However, when I call `$("#frmAddNew").valid())`, it always returns 'true'.
I don't know if its knockout, jQuery or mvc which is preventing the validation from returning false.

Comment: have you tried using it without knockoutjs to see if the validation works?

Comment: Hi, quick test shows same rendered html works when not inside <script type="text/html"></script>. Validation seems broken inside them. I need this for ko and templating so not sure how to get round this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(yourFormElement)` to get your `data-` attributes related to validation parsed.

You could trigger it like:

```
<div id="dlgAdd" data-bind="template: { name: 'editTemplate', data: selected, afterRender: hookUpValidation  }">
</div>
```

then, hookUpValidation would look like:

```
hookUpValidation: function(nodes) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(nodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but not luck. It only seems to work when I add the class="required" explicitly to the mark-up, yet MVC3 renders the model so the markup includes data annotation attributes so that 'data-val-required' is used.  Why would it work with 'required' but not 'data-val-required'?

Comment: OK- I think that the issue could be that your form is wrapped in a div and nodes[0] that I listed would be that div.  You need to call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` on the form.  Try like: `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form", nodes[0]));` .  Here is a sample that uses the same scripts that MVC3 uses: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UtvPS/

Comment: @Jon - just curious if you found a solution that worked and/or if you still had problems after the previous comment.

Comment: I've just put this on hold while I get chance to re-visit it. Will let you know how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: My form validation works as you said but I called it like so:

hookupValidation: function(nodes) {             
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#frmAdd"));
},

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into the code of jQuery validate and I think it doesn't work for dynamically added forms (which what Knockout does).

Take a look at this > [Jquery Validation Plugin, dynamic form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219485/jquery-validation-plugin-dynamic-form-validation)

You need to call the validate() method in a an event handler registered using the jQuery live() method. The live method links to all the dynamically added elements as well.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Mmm, seems strange that I have to use the 'mouseover' event to do this.  Is there no other fix for this? I'm expecting the validation function should work ok with the jquery templates.

Comment: I think its not about the mouseover event but the live() method. You must be calling the validate() function in the submit event of the form. Was the event registered using the jQuery.live() method?